# solr dependent search filters

Tags: database, solr, facet

I have a solr indexer with following fields

```
year
make
model
horsepower
color
price
```

these are interdependent

like

- make depend on year
- model depend on make + year
- horsepower depend on make+year+model and so on....

suppose i have a query

```
year = 2015 & make = bmw & model = a4 & horsepower = 300 & color = red
```

Now I want to get all facets in one solr query

```
like list of years
list of make where year = 2015
list of model where year = 2015 and make= bmw and so on
```

Is there any technique or possible way of achieving this via solr.

--
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at pivot facets introduced in Solr 4.10 and described here: http://lucidworks.com/blog/pivot-facets-inside-and-out/

You can try something like this:

`/select?q=*:*
     &facet=true
     &facet.pivot.mincount=1
     &facet.pivot=year,make,model`

Comment: Mihalcea: No "link only" answers, plz.